# Identifying an element of a web page based on attributes in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Python v 3.12.0 Selenium v 4.17.2 Chrome v 121.0.6167.160 (Official Build) (arm64) Macbook Air OS v 14.2.1 (23C71)

Hi,

I'm new to Selenium and HTML. I'm trying to write short tennis court booking script against a generic site 'gotcourts.com' which homes the booking sheet of my tennis club. There is an image of the webpage below with the associated HTML code. There are 11 courts, the first eight of which are external courts and the final three are internal courts. External courts 5-8 are not open during the winter season so they are blocked out.

I'd like to identify an internal court by calendarRow (so I can get the right court) and title (so I can get the right time) and return the value of the class (so I can tell before sending a click, whether the court is already booked). Note the class changes depending the court is unavailable, booked or (by default) available.

I've spent quite a time looking at this but have not managed to work out how to do it. My nearest attempts are:

```
courts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='calendarSlots']/div[@class='calendarSlotsForSport']/div[@class='calendarRow']/div[@title='15:00']")
```

Which interestingly only has 7 elements (the calendarRows for out of service courts are not included - don't understand why)

```
courts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='calendarSlots']/div[@class='calendarSlotsForSport']/div[@class='calendarRow'][9]")
courts2 = courts.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[title="15:00"]')
print("courts2: ",courts2)
```

which prints an element:

courts2:  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="98c13f451089026fb91ddef4e1d8e21e", element="f.76106E64D664766C5D798D2DFF30079D.d.30B03448A41BC22026B8BBA64E0617A0.e.180")>

but when I change the print statement to:

```
print("courts2: ",courts2.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

prints nothing.
Many thanks for any guidance regarding what I should be writing to meet my goal, or hints what I have done wrong gratefully considered.

[image: Webpage booking calendar with associated HTML.]

Comment: The div you selected in your screenshot doesn't seem to contain any content between the opening and closing div tags. Maybe you want to try `outerHTML`?

Comment: That works, thanks. Substituting outerHTML with class, data-type or any other of the attributes gets me the info I need. Many thanks!

Comment: I see you are on gotcourts.com but you didn't give us the name of your club. Would you please include a link to your club so we can see the specific page you are interacting with?

Comment: From the HTML you've posted, it looks like the page you are on is different than the page I can get to. I'm assuming that's because I don't have an account on the site. Instead, update your question with some of the relevant HTML as text instead of an image.

Comment: Hi JeffC,
Thanks for the time you have taken to review my question. Unfortunately it is a private club so not only do you have to have a gotcourts account (free) but you would have to have paid a subscription to the club in order to access the page so even with an account you would not be able to see it.
Regarding the HTML as text - good point. I did try to copy it however the maximum amount I can copy seems to be one element. (I can't select everything). (I am in view - developer - inspect elements on chrome) It would take a long time to copy paste everything .

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you've posted, it looks like a CSS selector

```
div.available
```

will locate all the open slots. From there, you could do something like print all the available times? For example,

```
slots = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.available")
print("Time slots open today:")
for slot in slots:
    print("  " + slot.get_attribute("title"))
```

and that should print something like

```
Time slots open today:
  13:00
  14:00
  15:00
  ...
```

Comment: With more of the relevant HTML or a link to the page, we could add things like what court, what day, etc. but that's not available in the HTML you provided.

Comment: Thanks for this. At the moment I have got things working using the hint from Pux. I have managed to identify - for example - the time of a slot using the code:
`courts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='calendarSlots']/div[@class='calendarSlotsForSport']/div[@class='calendarRow']['index']")`

`courts2 = courts.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[title=\"' + HourOfReservation + '\"]')`
I don't like mix of CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH methods so I will try to clean these up a bit in the future. (I'm still not great with the syntax, so good practice for me)